# Going to the router URL directly is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router, and everything is working fine except when I go to the URL directly. For example, if I clicked on a Link in the app that goes to "/quizreview?quizId=nAUl3DmFlX" it works with no problem. But if I entered the URL "http://localhost:3000/quizreview?quizId=nAUl3DmFlX" it says:

Cannot GET /quizreview?quizId=nAUl3DmFlX

Here is my router code:

```
ReactDOM.render((
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={UserQuiz} onEnter={loginRequired}/>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
        <Route path="/quiz/:id" component={Quiz}/>
        <Route path="/quizreview" component={PostQuiz}/>
        <Route path="/quizquestions/:quizId" component={QuestionForm}/>
        <Route path="/questionreview/:questionId" component={QuestionReview}/>
        <Route path="/noquestions" component={NoQuestionsDialog}/>
    </Route>
</Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? I followed the React-Router tutorial and it's working fine and I believe I followed the same instructions but with this problem occuring.

Comment: React isn't my strong point, but my guess would be that where you're locking this behind `loginRequired`, upon directly visiting the URL the user is no longer authenticated and thus the module gets blocked from loading. If that isn't the case, try using `hashHistory` instead of `browserHistory`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the HTML5, then to visit the URL directly with browserHistory you need to have  `historyApiFallback: true` in your webpack file if you are using webpack

what `historyApiFallback` does, is make it so your server returns `index.html` for whatever URL you try to access and since your routes are then configured with respect to index.html so you can access any of the route url directly

or else you can try and alternative i.e to use `history={hashHistory}` with `react-router` and then visit your url like

```
http://localhost:3000/#/quizreview?quizId=nAUl3DmFlX
```

Comment: Just to add to this a little: what `historyApiFallback` does, is make it so your server returns `index.html` for whatever URL you try to access. You can set up pretty much any server to act this way (and it's what you'd need to do to use `browserHistory` in production).

Comment: Glad to have helped.